# Suppose $(a_i)_{i=1}^{\infty}$ is square summable. Is $(\frac{a_i}{i})_{i=1}^\infty$ absolutely summable?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, complex-analysis, summation

Suppose $(a_i)_{i=1}^{\infty}$ is square summable. Is $(\frac{a_i}{i})_{i=1}^\infty$ absolutely summable?

Asked another way, say we have that $\sum a_i^2 \lt \infty$. Does this imply that $\sum|\frac{a_i}{i}|\lt\infty$?

I think the answer is "yes," but I'd be grateful for a demonstration either way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality,
$$
\sum\Bigl|\frac{a_i}i\Bigr|\le\Bigl(\sum a_i^2\Bigr)^{1/2}\Bigl(\sum i^{-2}\Bigr)^{1/2}<\infty.
$$

Comment: While this is a very slick method, I feel that applying Cauchy-Schwarz is a bit overpowered (never thought I'd say that!). The original question could be set as an exercise for an Analysis I course, where the students should only use elementary result that they've proved. Still, is a slick answer!

Comment: @SamT I agree. It was just the first thing that came to my mind. A more simple way would be to use the AM-GM inequality.

Comment: Yeah, maybe. It's nice that there are three such different answers, all pretty elementary, using different methods :) -- you get my +1 :)

Comment: @SamT Cauchy-Schwarz is in the realm of undergraduate mathematics, not overpowered at all. I agree with you about it being nice to have 3 completely different answers.

Comment: Oh yeah, I realise that it's undergraduate stuff, even first year. Just it isn't necessary to prove this result. One could perhaps phrase this in terms of a Taylor series of some function and show that we're inside its radius of convergence: this would be first year analysis material, but overkill. :) -- **but**, what's the point of proving results if you then don't use them!

Comment: This question was actually motivated by studying Fourier series of absolutely continuous 1-periodic functions with $L^2[0,1]$ derivatives. For example, it's easy to show that the Fourier coefficients of such a function f are $\frac{-i}{2\pi n}a_n$ where $a_n$ is the nth Fourier coefficient of f'. It's a small step to show that the Fourier coefficients of f are in $\ell^1$. Total brainfart. I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: 
$$
\frac{|a_i|}{i} \leq \frac{1}{2i^2} + \frac{1}{2} a_i^2.
$$

Comment: Dude, you beat me by 6 seconds =P -- that is quite a cool method though! I wouldn't have thought of using that, just do it directly

Comment: Is this by Young's Inequality?

Comment: Yes, but in its easiest form $|ab| \leq (a^2+b^2)/2$, that you can prove observing that $0\leq (|a| - |b|)^2 = a^2 + b^2 - 2|ab|$.

Comment: This is a nice little observation. I expect you could generalise it fairly easily to show that $\sum_i |a_i|^{2/3}/i$ converges, for example. +1! :)

Answer (score 0):

If $\sum_i a_i^2 < \infty$, then by the comparison test we must have $|a_i| \le 1/\sqrt{i}$ for $i$ sufficiently large, say $|a_i| \le i^{-1/2}$ for all $i \ge I$. This in particular says that $|a_i/i| \le i^{-3/2}$ for $i \ge I$, and hence is summable. (Split the sum $\sum_i$ into $\sum_{i < I} + \sum_{i \ge I}$ to see this final claim.)